# Remove black screen while navigating from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity

My app is facing a problem. My app has a button in one `activity` which will display a list of Wi-fi Printers in another `activity`.

But while moving from one `activity` to another a black screen appears and then I get the list of printers.

Point to be Noted :  I have a `LIST` not an `array of list`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You should post your code in the printers activity. It sounds like you are retrieving them on the UI thread and then displaying them which is why you see the black screen before they load

Comment: I m using a controller to talk to my UI... no direct code on my UI..

Comment: You still need to talk to this controller for your UI to work. When you search for Wifi printers (talking to the controller or however you are doing it) you are likely doing so on the main thread which locks up the app.

Comment: yeah u are right.. actually my controller is returning a list of printers.. i tried a lot to put a progress bar while searching .. as usual didn't work.. I m totally new so .. kindly help me !!

Comment: take a look at what userSeven7s said about AsyncTasks.. AsyncTasks are very useful for performing long running tasks in the background.

Comment: yeah i got it.. i will try this code.. but if u got any other suggestion i will like to try it .. nyway thanks.. :)

Comment: I'd use an AsyncTask for something like this so that's my suggestion :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` for searching printers. Execute the asynctask in `OnCreate()` of the listing activity, and show a progress dialog until search finishes. Check [documentation here with exmple](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)